# Unable to load pdb symbols where mdb path is being loaded as Symbol file location Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, pdb-files

My project is referencing a dll which has its code developed as another solution.
I was able to debug that once by referring the pdb path in the debugging symbols.

Today, I made few changes to the dll source code and trying to debug the same way by updating the pdb file in actual solution.

I could see that under Debug -> Windows -> Modules: the symbol is loaded for that dll but the symbol file location has different extension as **.dll.mdb**  ( it is getting generated on build)

**Note: I have added the pdb file location (location of .pdb file) in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols**

Can someone help me why this .mdb file is being generated in the folder where the actual .dll and .pdb files are present and replacing the .pdb file location in Symbols?